# When would one use the "extension" property (inherited from "FileSystemInfo") of the "DirectoryInfo" class?

Tags: .net, directoryinfo

The `Extension` property is inherited from `FileSystemInfo`.

When would you use it? As far as I know, DirectoryInfo represents directories and the actions you can perform on a directory. This would never include the need for an "extension".

What's the use of this property for the `DirectoryInfo` class?

Comment: It is there because property cannot be "uninherited" in .net ;-)

Comment: Try it on @"c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0"

Comment: @Hans: I don't understand. Surely "0" is not the "extension" of that directory (since I don't think directories have extensions. . . or do they?). . . Definition of the property is - Gets the string representing the extension part of the file. (Inherited from FileSystemInfo.)

Comment: They do.  "0" is the extension.  Windows merely defines it as whatever letters are after the last period.  Try DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories("*.0") on c:\program files for more evidence.

Comment: @Hans: Ok thanks. Doesn't make much sense to me though, based on the _english_ definition of an extension. Do you know anywhere that I can learn more about directories having extensions? Or maybe even better, when and where and why would someone ever use an extension on a directory?

Comment: You are putting too much stock into extensions being special.  It is a very primitive kind of file metadata, dating from the stone-age of computing.  The kind that has no obvious use for a directory.  So it just doesn't matter.  Unless you make it matter, you do have that option.

Comment: I guess what I'm really driving at is understanding the inheritance between FileSystemInfo and FileInfo and DirectoryInfo, and why the BCL writers chose to make that property available to both FileInfo and DirectoryInfo, when the property seemed to have no use for DirectoryInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would a `DirectoryInfo` object *never* include the need for an "extension"?

Names like `foo.dir`, `bar.ext` and `foo.bar` are perfectly legal for directories, in NTFS and many other filesystems.

Comment: Yes, but is "dir" the extension of directory "foo.dir"? I don't think so, but maybe I'm wrong. I thought an extension was to define the type of file.

Comment: @Richard: Yes, `dir` is the extension of directory `foo.dir`. There's nothing magic about extensions. They're just defined as the part of the filename after the last `.`, and they happen to have been used historically, by convention, to identify the "type" of the file.